# Angle of sector formed by cutting a cone

Tags: geometry, angle, convex-cone

A cone has a height of 10cm and circular base with radius 4.it is slit and cut open to form a sector.find the angle formed by the two radii.which is the simplest method to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $a$ the edge of the cone, $h$ its height and $r$ its radius: by  *Pythagoras*, $\; a=\sqrt{r^2+h^2}$.

The sector obtained has radius $a$. If its angle is $\theta$, its area is $\;\mathcal A=\frac12\theta a^2$.

On the other hand, this area is equal to the lateral area of the cone, which is equal to  $\;\pi ra$. So
$$\frac12\theta a^2=\pi ra\iff \theta=\frac{2\pi r}{a}.$$
(angles are in radians).

Comment: Please add _'this area is equal to the **lateral surface** area of the cone'_.

Comment: @CiaPan: You're right: it was implicit, but it's better saying it.

Answer (score 0):

The angle (in radians) of a circular sector is a ratio of the arc length and the sector's radius, $l/R$. The arc lenght is a circumference of your cone's base
$$l=2\pi r$$
and the radius is a slant height of the cone, i.e. the distance from the apex to the base edge:
$$R=\sqrt{h^2+r^2}$$

So the answer is
$$angle = \frac lR = \frac{2\pi r}{\sqrt{h^2+r^2}}=\frac{8\pi\,\text{cm}}{\sqrt{116}\,\text{cm}}\approx 2.33\,\text{rad}\approx 133^\circ$$

Comment: Thanks friends!I kindly appreciate all your efforts to answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that you know the circumference of the base of the cone, $2\pi r$, which is the same as the arc length of the flattened sector, $\sqrt{r^2+h^2}\,\theta$.

$$\theta=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{h^2}{r^2}}}.$$

[image]